# Changing listView checkBox image

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a listView with checkBoxes. Instead of the default image (unchecked/checked), I want to display an arrow pointing upwards or downwards. The arrow is already added as an image resource in my program, I just do not know how exactly to replace the default image to my custom image.

If I try `listView1.CheckBoxes.`, I can only select from `CompareTo, Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, GetTypeCode, ToString`, I do not see anything that will let me change the image. Is it even possible?

Comment: *"I do not see anything that will let me change the image"* - I'd be surprised if you would be able to do so using [bool property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkboxes(v=vs.110).aspx) ;) Really, check msdn first, it's good enough. As for the question, you can use owner-drawn `ListView` (see [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13006/Extended-ListView) or [this](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2016/08/make-an-ownerdraw-listview-in-c/)) and in addition handle mouse/keyboard to simulate checking/unchecking. Another option is to use `DataGridView`.

Comment: Whenever you ask about a ListView it is highly recommended to also tell us which View Mode it is in!!

Comment: It is in List view mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [ImageList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist(v=vs.110).aspx) component to form. Add two images to `Images` property.

Then set that `ImageList` to [StateImageList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.stateimagelist(v=vs.110).aspx) property on `ListView`. That two images will be use as checked/unchecked marks.

Comment: Don't forget to adapt the quality&size setting of the imagelist as needed!

Comment: I can't believe that the solution was so simple, thank you. Is there any way to make the check boxes true or false depending on the data in the listView?