# Changing the default ListView checkbox icons to my own ones

Tags: winforms, checkbox

I have followed the helpful guidance from Alexander Petrov here [Changing listView checkBox image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109511/changing-listview-checkbox-image)
but I can't get it to work.

I have added an `ImageList` control to my form, just by dragging it onto the form, and have added my two images to the `Images` collection as shown here:

[image: My Imagelist1]

I have then set the `StateImageList` to my new `ImageList1` and rebuilt all.

[image]

but I still get the Windows default checkbox icons.

[image]

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's Windows 11 in Tablet (or Convertible) mode.

Comment: Hi Jimi, could you please provide more detail and if possible, what I would need to do to both check and correct the issue if it is as you describe.

Comment: What does *if it is as you describe* mean? Is it or not?

Comment: Sorry, what I was try to say (badly) was that I don't understand what you mean by "Maybe it's Windows 11 in Tablet (or Convertible) mode". Is this a compile option? Or do you think that my instance of Windows desktop is erroneously flipping into this mode?  So could you please provide more detail on what I should be looking for.

Comment: It's not about the code. If you have Windows 11 in Tablet, Convertible or otherwise a Touch Screen, the rendering of the checkboxes is handled internally to provide the same *look & feel* everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that Jimi. As it happens, whilst I am indeed developing this on a laptop running Windows 11, it's not a convertable device and does not have a touch screen. I appreciate you trying to help with this and whilst it's something that I would like to get right, it's not critical, so I'm planning to leave it as-is for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was between the chair and the keyboard i.e. me!

I have two listview controls that sit on top of each other and are alternately shown or hidden. I had made the changes to one but the other was displayed by default, hence I couldn't see the changes. I have now updated both as detailed above and they work fine.